# Window10 iis Simultaneous Download Problem

Tags: iis, ftp, window

Tested on Windows 10 home version of iis ftp server.
It is attempting to download 1GB of files from 20 Android devices at the same time.
However, the maximum number of simultaneous downloads is only two.
The maximum number of connections for the ftp setting is 4294967295.

Twenty devices will attempt to log in to ftp under one account and download it.
I don't think this is a problem.

My ultimate goal is to download more than 10 simultaneous downloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the windows10's IIS has the connection limit, it just support three client connect to the IIS at same time.

If you want to increase this number, please use windows server instead.